# Executing a fully executable spring boot application jar in unix

Tags: java, unix, spring-boot, jar

I have a Spring Boot Application which I have exported as a fully executable jar from eclipse having all the required dependency jars.
I am executing the jar using the following command: java -jar kafka.jar
The code contains 4 packages.
While executing it throws the following exception:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: URL [rsrc:com/bt/kakfaMessage/controller/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: rsrc:com/bt/kakfaMessage/controller/

Can someone suggest how to execute this jar? The code works perfectly fine when executed from my local eclipse.

Comment: A _fully executable_ jar (as defined in https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#deployment-install) should not be run using `java -jar`

Comment: You shouldn't export the jar from eclipse you should use maven or gradle and let the Spring Boot plugin do its work. Then you either start it with` java -jar` or (if done correctly and as explained in the reference guide) you can simply execute it as it will be a script as well.